# login ssh ubuntu stalls on WSL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ssh, login

I'm trying to login to a remote server with ssh, but when I try to run

```
ssh -p 2022 user@hostname
```

ubuntu is stalling, aborting the command gives me the error:

```
ssh: connect to host hostname port 2022: Connection timed out
```

i've also tried by replacing hostname with IP address without success.

What can i do? There's something wrong in my configuration, i can access normally from another machine.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you specify port 2022? Connection timeout  means you do not have route to the remote server. It can be that the remote server is not allowing you to make connection to that server on the specified port. Normally ssh connections are made on port 22. Try port 22.
You can also check connectivity between your machine and remote server by doing a telnet on the port you are interested(`telnet hosntname 22`).